# Install JIRA on Ubuntu 12.04 with the default installer or manually?

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, jira

I am researching installing JIRA, and the rest of the Atlassian Suite, onto an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

It appears that not long ago everyone recommended installing JIRA manually. This was due to lots of configuration problems and bugs related to Java 7.

I found a manual installation guide, but I would prefer to be lazy and have the install automated.

[Ubuntu 12.04 /12.10 Ultimate Atlassian Production Server : Crowd + JIRA + Confluence + Stash + Fisheye | Single Sign On (SSO) | Fully Integrated | PostgreSQL ( pgSQL ) + Oracle Java 1.7( JDK 7 ) + Apache2 + SSL ( https ) + SNI (Shared SSL) + PROXY_AJP ( ajp ) + Optimised](https://extremeshok.com/2013/01/30/ubuntu-12-04-12-10-atlassin-hosted-server-apache2-httpd-ssl-https-tomcat-stash-2-jira-confluence-postgresql-pgsql-oracle-java-1-8-jdk-8/)

**Does the default JIRA installer for linux work well?**

**Is there a reason to manually install JIRA?**

Comment: You should be able to answer the first question yourself, have you already tried it?

Comment: No, I wanted to get the communities advice first. I wanted to see if people had experience with the installer and if all the recent problems had been fixed. Un-installation of JIRA is probably not trivial and I would like to install it using the best method, the first time.

Comment: Removing Jira **is** trivial. One application directory, one data directory, an init script, and the database is all its comprised of.

Comment: That is good to know. Thanks for the information. I will proceed with using the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is the most supported method, which is the installer. As noted above, JIRA is quite well-contained, and is trivial to uninstall manually if need be.

The installer puts things in the expected places so future upgrades will be trivial as well.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer. I will use the installer. I know that the installer runs it's own Java and Tomcat instances. Hopefully, JIRA will work with stock Ubuntu and Virtualmin.

Comment: Virtualmin? Yikes. Get that garbage off of your server.

Comment: Alternatives to Virtualmin?

Comment: HumanMin a.k.a SysadMin

Comment: You got me. I actually googled those. Is there seriously no good GUI interface for linux server management?

Comment: @dbasch - These GUI control panels are an abomination. They do things in unexpected ways, they obfuscate what's really going on, and make it near impossible to troubleshoot or get support. If you're going to have a Linux server, it's well worth your time to learn real command-line administration. It will be well worth the effort.